# How to List TCP/UDP Connections in iOS 4

Tags: ios, sockets, ios4, network-programming

I am interested in deriving a list of active TCP/UDP network connections on an iOS 4.3 device.  Basically, I'm looking for the same type of information one gets from issuing a "netstat -anp tcp" (or the same, but with udp) command under OS X Darwin.

I've searched Apple's iOS Developer Library (especially NSNetServices, CFNetServices, and the iOS Manual Pages) and the Internet, but with no good results.  Yet, there is an iOS Netstat app (see http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2) out there, so it appears possible.

Thanks in advance for any useful pointers/suggestions/thoughts.

Comment: Sure--but I believe it relies on there being a /proc file system through which to rifle.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to read device files directly in iOS so I don't see a solution. :/

Comment: I agree the solution seems somewhat elusive (which is why I bring the question to this fine forum!).  Nevertheless, there is an iOS app (i.e., referenced above in my question) that appears to operate like the traditional netstat utility.

Answer (score 9):

I believe I have now answered my own question.  Thought I had taken a close enough look at the sysctl() library function, but I hadn't!  For example, the following will yield information about the current TCP connections:

```
sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", ...)
```

To get information about UDP connection, simply use a different Management Information Base (MIB) name:  net.inet.udp.pcblist.

For convenience, here's a link to the appropriate iOS man page:

```
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how to "parse" the data retrieved from this method? I am trying to get all current open sockets.

Comment: Got the parsing ok. But do you know if there is a way of "linking" each connection to a specific process/service?

Comment: @JonasAndersson,How did you parse the data? please give some code.

Comment: any help with the parsing?