# How to get tcp/udp opening port list on iphone by objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, port

Hi I want to get all tcp/udp opening port status list on iphone by objective-c? like netstat on Linux, Do you know how to achieve it or it there any API　can do that?  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to List TCP/UDP Connections in iOS 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527065/how-to-list-tcp-udp-connections-in-ios-4)

Comment: You can get list of open TCP/UDP port connection on iphone.No need of jailbreak. No app Rejection on appstore. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14252327/999277) answer

Answer (score 5):

You can't run `netstat` on an iPhone (unless you jailbreak it), but you can do what `netstat` does.  Take a look at function `protopr` in [the `netstat` source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-307/netstat.tproj/inet.c).  I verified that you can call `sysctlbyname` with `"net.inet.tcp.pcblist"` as the name and get back a bunch of data.  I didn't try to interpret the data like `netstat` does.

Test case:

```
size_t len = 0;
if (sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", 0, &len, 0, 0) < 0) {
    perror("sysctlbyname");
} else {
    char *buf = malloc(len);
    sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", buf, &len, 0, 0);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buf length:len];
    NSLog(@"data = %@", data);
}
```

Output on my iPad 2 running iOS 5.0:

```
2011-11-17 19:59:34.712 keyboardtest[29423:707] data = <18000000 2c000000 9e2a0900
00000000 c60e5d00 00000000 0c020000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 d4d3d4d2
00000000 00000000 ...
```

and lots more I have truncated.

Make sure you're initializing `len` to 0.  Also, you can't just put the contents of `buf` in an `NSString` as if it were a C string.  It's not.  It's binary data that you have to interpret, like `netstat` does.

Presumably you want to interpret the data.  You need to read through the `protopr` function in the `netstat` source code, which I linked to above.  The data structures used by `protopr` are declared in `<netinet/in_pcb.h>`, `<netinet/tcp_var.h>`, and other header files in `/usr/include/netinet`.  These header files are included in the iOS SDK (as of iOS 7.0 at least), so you can use them.

Comment: Hi: I use following code, but output nothing,                                  size_t size;
sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *port = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", port, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *portList = [NSString stringWithCString:port];
free(port); NSLog(@"%@",portList);

Comment: Thanks! Any leads on how to interpret it?

Answer (score 4):

To get the data obtained by the rob mayoff's answer readable you just need to take a look at the code of [inet.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-396.6/netstat.tproj/inet.c). In it, you have all you need to parse the data.

Take a look at my another answer in the question of Hisenberg: [Network Activity Monitoring on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977759/network-activity-monitoring-on-iphone/20108521#20108521)

In my [code](https://github.com/dcorbatta/StackoverflowTest/tree/master/InetTest), you can see in what part of the code the data is readable, that is when I add the values to the dictionary.