# In iOS, what is type of buf return by 'sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", buf, &len, 0, 0)'?

Tags: ios

I want to get list of tcp connection on my iPhone.
I got following code on 
[How to get tcp/udp opening port list on iphone by objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176839/how-to-get-tcp-udp-opening-port-list-on-iphone-by-objective-c)
[How to List TCP/UDP Connections in iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527065/how-to-list-tcp-udp-connections-in-ios-4)

```
size_t len = 0;
if (sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", 0, &len, 0, 0) < 0) {
    perror("sysctlbyname");
} else {
    char *buf = malloc(len);
    sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", buf, &len, 0, 0);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buf length:len];
    NSLog(@"data = %@", data);
}
```

But I am unable to interpret variable 'buf' as it points to some structure and not string. 
What could be the type of buf?
Can someone help me...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Here buf is a stuct type xpingen.
xinpgen *oxig, *xig;
oxig = xig = (struct xinpgen *)buf;

Comment: @Tanu you need to mark this answer as the answer as it is the answer (:

Comment: This type doesn't seem to be available when building for iOS device